# deploying wsp onto a different sharepoint server

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

I have created a share point project that works on a development share point site.

When I compile it to WSP and upload it to share point online, and activate it, it doesnt work..

I always start with an empty share point solution and set it as a sandbox setting. I connect it in visual studio to my development share point page (which is different to my online share point, different GUID ect)

Do I need to change setting to make it work on the different server?

Comment: do you have anymore information? when does it fail? do you have codebehind? is your development page also online or is it on your development environment?

Comment: there is no info here, what you mean with activation? deployed? does it says error on central admin on deployment steps:? if so, what is the error on the uls logs? or did you have to activate some features and the error is on the feature activation, this question really lacks lots of information.